# Obtener suma total de registros agrupados en la misma fila

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Soy nuevo en SQL, tengo una Vista Partos, la cual he logrado contar el numero de partos usando group by

```
SELECT YEAR(fechaparto) AS año, MONTH(fechaparto) AS mes,
tipoparto, COUNT(tipoparto) AS NumeroPartos
FROM  dbo.SETI_TablaE 
GROUP BY YEAR(fechaparto), MONTH(fechaparto), tipoparto
```

como se muestra continuación:

[image: Mi vista actual]

lo que necesito es añadir al final un columna TotalPartos las cual seria la suma de Nro de partos pero por año, mes y tipoparto, la salida que necesito seria la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier apoyo para añadir o modificar mi consulta seria de gran ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si conviertes tu consulta actual en un CTE, puedes hacer un `sum()` sobre la *[partición de ventana](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)* `año, mes`, con lo cual la consulta, en mi opinión, queda muy fácil de leer y de darle mantenimiento.

```
with
Resumen as (
select   year(fechaparto) año
       , month(fechaparto) mes
       , tipoparto
       , count(1) NumeroPartos
  from SETI_TablaE
 group by year(fechaparto) 
       , month(fechaparto) 
       , tipoparto
)
select   año 
       , mes
       , tipoparto
       , NumeroPartos
       , sum(NumeroPartos) over (partition by año, mes) TotalPartos
  from Resumen
```

En mis pruebas devuelve:

```
año         mes         tipoparto NumeroPartos TotalPartos
----------- ----------- --------- ------------ -----------
2016        7           CESAREA   9            20
2016        7           VAGINAL   11           20
2016        8           CESAREA   9            12
2016        8           VAGINAL   3            12

(4 rows affected)


Completion time: 2020-08-05T11:57:53.5750196-06:00
```

Si no quieres usar *CTE*, puedes hacer una sola consulta valiéndote siempre de las [funciones de ventana](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), en este caso, `count`:

```
select   distinct 
         year(fechaparto) año
       , month(fechaparto) mes
       , tipoparto
       , count(1) over (partition by year(fechaparto), month(fechaparto), tipoparto) NumeroPartos 
       , count(1) over (partition by year(fechaparto), month(fechaparto)) TotalPartos
  from SETI_TablaE
```

En mi opinión, es un poco más difícil de digerir, pero da el resultado esperado.

Comment: Funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez la forma más sencilla y consistente con el estándar SQL, es usar una subconsulta para obtener los totales por mes y año, e integrarlos con un JOIN a tu consulta actual:

```
SELECT YEAR(T1.fechaparto) AS año, 
       MONTH(T1.fechaparto) AS mes,
       T1.tipoparto, 
       COUNT(T1.tipoparto) AS NumeroPartos,
       T2.NumeroPartos     AS TotalPartos
       FROM  dbo.SETI_TablaE T1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT YEAR(fechaparto) AS año, 
                          MONTH(fechaparto) AS mes,
                          COUNT(tipoparto) AS NumeroPartos
                          FROM  dbo.SETI_TablaE
                          GROUP BY YEAR(fechaparto), 
                                   MONTH(fechaparto)
               ) T2
               ON T1.año = T2.año
               AND T1.mes = T2.mes

       GROUP BY YEAR(T1.fechaparto), 
                MONTH(T1.fechaparto),
                T1.tipoparto
```